# Warum steht eine Spraydose unter Druck?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

Warum steht z.B. eine Spraydose unter Druck? Müsste Sie nicht vielmehr über Druck stehen, da in ihr ein Überdruck herrscht?

Ein abgetauchtes U-Boot hingegen würde unter Druck stehen, da hier ein Unterdruck herrscht?

Comment: Es ist nicht unbedingt so, dass automatisch die *erste* im Wörterbuch gefundene Bedeutung eines Wortes die Richtige ist - es könnte auch die dritte oder vierte sein - hier ist es (im Online-Duden) die zehnte.

Comment: Im Wasser herrscht aber sowas von Überdruck! Nur weil man *unter* Wasser ist, ist da noch lange kein Unterdruck. Je mehr Wassersäule desto mehr Druck auf ein Objekt. Man kann auch *unter Zeitdruck* stehen, aber es gibt weder *Zeitunterdruck* noch *Zeitüberdruck*.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Irrtum. In einem U-Boot unter Wasser herrscht *Unterdruck*, weil drumrum der Druck höher ist als im Boot. Deswegen wird aber die Vermutung in der Frage nicht richtiger.

Comment: @Tofro Wie ich sagte. Das Wasser übt auf ein Objekt unter Wasser einen höheren Druck aus, je tiefer das Objekt geht. Deswegen haben wir Taucher es auch nicht leicht. Ist eine Frage der Sichtweise. Ich als Taucher werde zusammengedrückt. Zusammendrücken geht nur, wenn mein Druck geringer ist. Ein Objekt unter Wasser wird aber einem steigenden Druck/Überdruck ausgesetzt. Daher ist die Aussage des OP zwar richtig (ein U-Boot unter Wasser steht unter Druck - durch die Wassersäule), aber nicht weil das Wasser einen Unterdruck ausübt, sondern im Gegenteil einen Überdruck.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Ich glaube nicht, dass diese Diskussion dem OP hier irgendetwas hilft. Ich bin gerne bereit, im Chat  mit dir darüber zu diskutieren, dass Über- bzw. Unterdruck immer *relativ* zu einem Umgebungsdruck sind.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

"unter Druck" stehen bedeutet: Die Spraydose steht unter dem Einfluss des Drucks. Der Druck übt Einfluss auf die Spraydose aus. Ebenso verhält es sich bei dem U-Boot. Dieses steht auch unter dem Einfluss des Drucks.
Das unter steht hier auch nicht für das räumliche unter, sondern, nach dem Duden, für "unter befindlich" sein. 
Deshalb *befindet* sich die Spraydose *unter* Druck.

Unter Druck stehen erklärt sich hier, da stehen auch die Bedeutung haben kann, in einem Verhältnis zu jemandem/etwas zu sein. Die Spraydose hat das Verhältnis zu dem Druck.

**HINWEIS**: Die Spraydose *steht* *unter Einfluss* der physikalischen Größe *Druck*.

Der Unterdruck und der Überdruck sind hier zwei Begriffe, welche eine jeweils nähere Beschreibung des Drucks sind.

Answer (score 8):

*Unter XYZ stehen* is a general German expression for something like *to be affected by XYZ*, so the *unter* in *unter Druck stehen* has nothing to do with *Unterdruck*, but means more or less *being affected by pressure*.

Comment: ＋１—compare semantics of “under the impression/influence” and “under pressure” as well.

Comment: Man steht auch unter Strom, unter Drogen, unter der Kontrolle der NSA usw. und nicht zuletzt unter Überdruck.